# Where is my error in phpseclib usage?

Tags: php, rsa, phpseclib

I'm trying to use phpseclib library

```
include 'phpseclib/vendor/autoload.php';
$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
$loader->addPsr4('phpseclib\\', DRUPAL_ROOT . '/path/phpseclib/');
$loader->register();
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;
```

if I use $rsa = new RSA();

```
function my_function() {
 $rsa = new RSA();
}
```

I have an error:

> Constants may only evaluate to scalar values in include() ... in
>   ...Crypt/RSA/PKCS1.php

If I'm writing

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA(); as this example http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/guide.html
```

I have an error:

> Class 'Crypt_RSA' not found in ...my_module.

What I do wrong?

The version phpseclib from this https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib from master branch

php -v is 5.3

Comment: Looks like a namespacing issue to me if phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php really is loaded

Comment: imo, for your version of PHP then this version: [phpseclib - PHP Secure Communications Library (V2.0)](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/2.0) will be more useful. If you read the `composer.json` file then it can be seen which version of PHP is required. The latest branch needs PHP 7+

Comment: Thank you, Ryan, the problem was in a version of PHP. It's working now.

Comment: @user3313412 - it looks like you're using the master branch. That version is under active development and the API has been getting a lot of changes. Until the master branch is actually assigned a version I'd recommend not using it and that you, instead, use the 2.0 version, as Ryan Vincent suggested.